# Calibrating a non-homogeneous Poisson process to my data

Tags: poisson-process, calibration

**My question:**

Let's say I have some data on the cumulative number of infections per day since the start of a pandemic at $t=0$. Since clearly the infection rate changes over time, I want to calibrate a non-homogeneous Poisson process $N(t)$ on this data, with a cumulative arrival rate $\Lambda(t)$ that I need to estimate (i.e., $E[N(t)] = \Lambda(t)$).

My question is how do you do this? How do you estimate the function $\Lambda$ from the data?

**My attempt to find an answer:**

I have thought of using the definition of a non-homogeneous Poisson process as $N(t) = N^{\star}(\Lambda(t))$, with $N^{\star}(t)$ a homogeneous Poisson process with rate $\lambda=1$. Indeed, when you want to simulate a non-homogeneous Poisson process $N(t)$ with known $\Lambda$, you simulate arrival times $a_n$ of $N^{\star}$(t), then find the arrival times $t_n$ for $N(t)$ through the equality $t_n = \Lambda^{-1}(a_n)$. So I thought, since I know $t_n$ from my data, I can maybe somehow find the function $\Lambda$ by simulating arrival times $a_n$ of $N^{\star}$ and then fit a polynomial or a spline through the points $(a_n, t_n)$.

Is this a correct way to proceed to calibrate a non-homogeneous Poisson process to my data? Or is there some more straightforward method?

Thanks in advance for any help.